# Show controls on taskbar application hover

Tags: c#, windows, uwp, uwp-xaml

Is there any way in UWP to build the Hover UI same like spotify:

[image]

I know in UWP we have System controls to show the controls when app is in background, can we use that to build same experience, if yes then how can I do it.

I have added  `<uap3:Capability Name="backgroundMediaPlayback" />` capability but i am getting below error.

```
Error   APPX0501    Validation error. error C00CE014: App manifest validation error: The app manifest must be valid as per schema: Line 62, Column 6, Reason: Element '{schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10/3}Capability' is unexpected according to content model of parent element '{schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10}Capabilities'. Expecting: {schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10}DeviceCapability <Packing-Path>\bin\x64\Debug\AppxManifest.xml    1
```

Comment: If the below answer is helpful please consider accept it.

Comment: Thanks @NicoZhu-MSFT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> can we use that to build same experience, if yes then how can i do it.

Sure, you could enable background audio with add Background media playback manifest capability. And the play control will display when your app minimize. For more detail please refer [**Play media in the background**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/background-audio) 
And this is [official code sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/BackgroundMediaPlayback) that you could refer.

Comment: Nico, Is there any way to do some customization of the hover UI, same like Skype

Comment: Error APPX0501 Validation error. error C00CE014: App manifest validation error: The app manifest must be valid as per schema: Line 62, Column 6, Reason: Element '{http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10/3}Capability' is unexpected according to content model of parent element '{http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10}Capabilities'. Expecting: {http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10}DeviceCapability <Packing-Path>\bin\x64\Debug\AppxManifest.xml 1

Comment: @PavanTiwari, it is system level, we could not do some customization UI.

Comment: It worked for me. but it works only when i keep  <uap3:Capability Name="backgroundMediaPlayback"/> after  <Capability Name="internetClient" />